# broadcast ps2wsh transaction failed

Tags: bitcoinjs, bip174-psbt, p2wsh

Greeting,

I hope someone can guide me about what is wrong with my p2wsh transaction hex below

```
020000000001014cf3b8d35c7b67fa3b669900f2a42b2e8b8a90487c2fca2b913b4e9d24a7b94e5d00000000ffffffff01e80300000000000022002053461e7b7bebf5089234af05cc4bfa5447ec7a9bc611c1f8d47dfc570a0339430221876bf128fa0fe05d617494045dc8dc27a530ec4d9c80e8d35eac377bd9c4e5090024a821876bf128fa0fe05d617494045dc8dc27a530ec4d9c80e8d35eac377bd9c4e509008700000000
```

i tried decode the hex and got result below :

```
{
"addresses": [
    "tb1qlwfxkadgkjykp24pcs699x3yx7egvm26khcpjheysknwv0ahh4zqmnc7xe",
    "tb1q2drpu7mma06s3y354uzucjl623r7c75mccgur7x50h79wzsr89psmcywrq"
],
"block_height": -1,
"block_index": -1,
"confirmations": 0,
"double_spend": false,
"fees": 1000,
"hash": "6ad4fce6043d8012105d6b2da5da3d8519124d8bf8c97fa5c1efad27a3dd72d9",
"inputs": [
    {
        "addresses": [
            "tb1qlwfxkadgkjykp24pcs699x3yx7egvm26khcpjheysknwv0ahh4zqmnc7xe"
        ],
        "age": 2579745,
        "output_index": 93,
        "output_value": 2000,
        "prev_hash": "4eb9a7249d4e3b912bca2f7c48908a8b2e2ba4f20099663bfa677b5cd3b8f34c",
        "script_type": "pay-to-witness-script-hash",
        "sequence": 4294967295,
        "witness": [
            "876bf128fa0fe05d617494045dc8dc27a530ec4d9c80e8d35eac377bd9c4e50900",
            "a821876bf128fa0fe05d617494045dc8dc27a530ec4d9c80e8d35eac377bd9c4e5090087"
        ]
    }
],
"outputs": [
    {
        "addresses": [
            "tb1q2drpu7mma06s3y354uzucjl623r7c75mccgur7x50h79wzsr89psmcywrq"
        ],
        "script": "002053461e7b7bebf5089234af05cc4bfa5447ec7a9bc611c1f8d47dfc570a033943",
        "script_type": "pay-to-witness-script-hash",
        "value": 1000
    }
],
"preference": "low",
"received": "2024-02-28T06:29:26.761160172Z",
"relayed_by": "54.226.234.175",
"size": 168,
"total": 1000,
"ver": 2,
"vin_sz": 1,
"vout_sz": 1,
"vsize": 113}
```

When i tried broadcast the raw transaction hex above, i got error "**non-mandatory-script-verify-flag (Script evaluated without error but finished with a false/empty top stack element)**"

I'm new to bitcoin development, and still struggle to understand by example.

Answer (score 0):

The witness script is the last element pushed on witness, and your case is `a821...`.

Your address is `tb1qlwf...`

A P2WSH address is `sha256(witness script)`, let's verify that:

```
$ hal address -t create --script a821876bf128fa0fe05d617494045dc8dc27a530ec4d9c80e8d35eac377bd9c4e5090087

{
  "p2sh": "2NGYBv4ryXa55wg8wTfMUhUSEAqJhe8AB4j",
  "p2wsh": "tb1qlwfxkadgkjykp24pcs699x3yx7egvm26khcpjheysknwv0ahh4zqmnc7xe",
  "p2shwsh": "2NAx9vPRkc5obFLPYG98YnpRFo7TodYkLqx",
  "p2tr": "tb1prrmgv7lpzwqgt7vkkdfndgzpwmpz4lts79j8f8htsaz8p08fmv9sjvqhky"
}
```

Yes, the value for `p2wsh` (`tb1qlwf...`) matches the address. So far so good.

Now let's decode your witness script `a821...`:

```
$ hal script decode a821876bf128fa0fe05d617494045dc8dc27a530ec4d9c80e8d35eac377bd9c4e5090087
 
OP_SHA256 OP_PUSHBYTES_33 876bf128fa0fe05d617494045dc8dc27a530ec4d9c80e8d35eac377bd9c4e50900 OP_EQUAL
```

This means it expects some value, which sha256 hash will be equal to `876b...`.

The value your are passing is `876b...`, i.e., the same value as the hash you're expecting. But this value, after being sha256 will be totally different, so the script will return false on `OP_EQUAL`

Let's verify that:

```
$ hal hash -t sha256 876bf128fa0fe05d617494045dc8dc27a530ec4d9c80e8d35eac377bd9c4e50900

80afc01a83b056ec8861420311387ab2dc57aab6b4b564c060b65049a8eda1de
```

Since `876b...` and `80af...` are different, the script fails.

To fix this, on the first element of witness you need to pass the value which sha256 is equal to `876b...`